# Is the CDF of a continuous RV invertible on the range of the RV?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that $X$ is a continuous random variable with the range $\Omega_X$ and the CDF $F_X$, is it always true that $F_X$ is invertible **on $\Omega_X$**?

Update:
Let $\Omega_X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_X(x) > 0\}$.

Comment: For a suitable definition of "range", yes.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I've updated my question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What you really want are the Lebesgue points of $F_X$, at which $\frac{dF_X}{dx}>0$ actually means something. If $f_X$ is everywhere continuous (which is not guaranteed just from $X$ being continuously distributed) then what you said is fine, since every point is a Lebesgue point in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, this is helpful. Could you explain why $f_X$ has to be continuous? I don't understand this part. My understanding is that if $f_X=\frac{dFx}{dx}$ is not continuous then $F_X$ is also not continuous, but $F_X$ doesn't have to be continuous to be invertible on $\Omega_X$.

Comment: So $F_X$ being continuous is just automatic from the assumption that $X$ is continuous. What I am saying is really that what you are thinking of as the "range" is a more subtle concept than you think it is, unless $f_X$ is everywhere continuous. This is because I have room to "play" with $f_X$ without actually changing the distribution, creating points where $f_X>0$ but which aren't really in the range of $X$.

Comment: A more robust definition of range is $x \in \Omega_X$ if and only if $P(X \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon))>0$ for all $\epsilon>0$. If you define $\Omega_X$ that way, then regardless of any other property of $X$, $F_X$ is strictly monotone on $\Omega_X$ (and invertible if there are no jumps).